# tri plannar mapping in three.js

Tags: three.js, glsl, game-engine, game-development

I am trying to do texture mapping with triplanner mapping in three.js in terrain created after heightmap data into plane mesh.

To do that i load the diffuse texture by

```
  let diffuseTex;
  loader.load(
    "./resources/images/satellite.png",
    function (image) {
      diffuseTex = image;
    },
    undefined,
    function () {
      console.error("An error happened.");
    }
  );
```

I did use that texture created from the diffusemap image that i have locally as an uniform

```
var uniforms1 = {
    diffuseTexture: { type: "t", value: diffuseTex },
  };

  const _meshMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms1,
    vertexShader: terrainShader._VS,
    fragmentShader: terrainShader._FS,
  });
```

My shader code is:

```
const _VS = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;

out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 vPosition;

#define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )

void main(){
    vNormal = normal;
    vPosition = position.xyz;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vPosition = vec3(gl_Position.xyz)*0.5 + 0.5;
    
  }
`;

const _FS = `#version 300 es

precision mediump sampler2DArray;
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;

in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vPosition;

out vec4 out_FragColor;

vec3 blendNormal(vec3 normal){
    vec3 blending = abs(normal);
    blending = normalize(max(blending, 0.00001));
    blending /= vec3(blending.x + blending.y + blending.z);
    return blending;
}

vec3 triplanarMapping (sampler2D tex, vec3 normal, vec3 position) {
  vec3 normalBlend = blendNormal(normal);
  vec3 xColor = texture(tex, position.yz).rgb;
  vec3 yColor = texture(tex, position.xz).rgb;
  vec3 zColor = texture(tex, position.xy).rgb;
  return (xColor * normalBlend.x + yColor * normalBlend.y + zColor * normalBlend.z);
}

void main(){
    vec3 color = triplanarMapping(diffuseMap, vNormal, vPosition);
    out_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

  }
`;
export const terrainShader = { _VS, _FS };
```

Then i create a mesh with the geometry which is filled with the vertices data and material created with custom shader:

```
let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(
      partial.x,
      partial.y,
      partial.x - 1,
      partial.y - 1
    );
    geometry.setFromPoints(chunk[i]);
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, _meshMaterial);
    mesh.castShadow = false;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(mesh);
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong because i am getting this as output of terrain:

[image]

I was expecting mapping of this texture above this terrain.

texture to map:

[image]

I am new to this and struggling can anyone please help me ?

Update:

I updated the material creation and placed material creation inside the texture loader callback like this:

```
loader.load(
    "./resources/images/satellite.png",
    function (texture) {
      var uniforms1 = {
        diffuseTexture: { type: "t", value: texture },
      };
      _meshMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms1,
        vertexShader: terrainShader._VS,
        fragmentShader: terrainShader._FS,
      });
```

and it brought this change to the output terrain to this image which was black terrain before in picture above, i dont know if it is good thing or bad but this is nowhere near what i wanted but wanted to put as an update because this post is my only hope now.

[image]

Comment: Once again, as I asked before, please provide a working example so others can recreate and address your issue.

Comment: @Marquizzo thank you for your response, i did put all code into fiddle but three.js loader.load( image url) is thowing error of CORS which is not going even if i am doing 
loader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");

Comment: because of it demo is not working but fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/c5htgjq0/4/

Comment: I changed my code in material creation with material creation in callback of loader.load()

Comment: update: after i changed the material creation only at the callback of the textureloader.load(), output look like this https://ibb.co/XxbzLFG which used to look like this before https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDJv6.png I have updated the post with the change in code and its affect on the output terrain